# How the code works after calling a method in java?

Tags: java, function, methods, subroutine

My question is ,"After calling mark() method, first "Allan" is printed and then "The Student's name is Allan" is printed. But I have called the output() method only  after printing "The Student's name is ".But in the output it's printing "Allan" first which is in the mark() method and then it's prints "My name is Allan". Please explain how the code actually works after calling mark() method .  "

```
class student {
    String name;
    int age;
    String gender;

    String mark() {
        System.out.println("Allan");
        return name;
    }
}

public class coke {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        student detail = new student();
        detail.name = "Allan";
        System.out.println("The Student's name is " + detail.mark());
    }
}
```

**Output: 
Allan**

**The Student's name is Allan**

If the provided details is not enough please request me . Please don't devote my question as it will permanently block me for asking questions in Stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a method, you have to evaluate the parameter first.

In the `main` method, the parameter of `System.out.println` is `"The Student's name is " + detail.mark()`.

To evaluate `"The Student's name is " + detail.mark()`, you need call `detail.mark()`. So, `System.out.println("Allan");` will be executed first.

Then you get the parameter `The Student's name is Allan` and execute `System.out.println("The Student's name is Allan");`

Comment: That's really helpful